early calculus question finding the root of $\cos(x) +2x -5$
Given $f(x)= \cos(x)+2x-5$ find c such that $f(c)=0$.  The x-intercept.
The problem is from a calculus class.
I got as far as noting that when $f(x)=0$, $\cos(x) = 2x-5$.  Therefore,
$$
-1 \le 2x-5 \le 1 \\
2 \le x \le 3 \\
$$
... but that’s some distance short of an answer.
Might be the approach involves the mean value theorem (MVT) and the squeeze theorem, but that’s just a hunch.
Thanks!

You're off to a good start.  If you're looking for a closed-form solution, I don't think there is one.  Numerically, $x \approx 2.994608641950846$.

The Mean Value Theorem, or the Intermediate Value Theorem?

Do you mean $\cos{x} = 5-2x$ ?

@ArturoMagidin I agree it has the IVT setup, but we were asked for an exact solution.  As far as I know IVT guarantees an intermediate point but not THE intermediate point.

Neither the IVT nor the MVT tell you what the point with the property is. They just tell you a point with the property (different property for each theorem) exists somewhere in the interval.

Might they want you to find a numerical solution by Newton's method or fixed point iteration? Note, too, that the slope, being greater than any slope on the periodic function, guarantees that there will be only one solution. Here is a little Python session:
>>> from math import cos
>>> x=2
>>> x=((5-cos(x))/2);x
2.708073418273571
>>> x=((5-cos(x))/2);x
2.953746528740264
>>> x=((5-cos(x))/2);x
2.9912043677190825

Related discussion on fixed-point forms is here and here.

Thanks, for context the question was on a test.  No python interpreters allowed :-).

Fixed point is easy to perform on a calculator. Type a number. Press enter. Use Ans to recall the previous number instead of $x$ in the equation, e.g. 2<enter>(5-cos([Ans]))/2<enter>, etc...

Pencil and paper only.

If you want an approximation by hand, Taylor expand $\cos{x}$ at $x=\pi$. Using only the first two terms in the expansion, $\cos{x} \approx -1 + \frac{1}{2}(x-\pi)^2$. You will obtain the equation $5-2x = -1 + \frac{1}{2}(x-\pi)^2$ or $$ x^2+(4-2\pi)x+\pi^2-12 = 0$$
which has the solution $x=\pi-2+2\sqrt{4-\pi} \approx 2.9946$.

You're off to a good start bounding $x$ to the interval $[2, 3]$.  Now, are there any special angles between 2 and 3 that you know the cosine of?
OK, maybe it's easier to answer if I phrase it this way: Are there any special angles between $0.63662\pi$ and $0.95493\pi$ that you know the cosine of?  If you have your $\frac{\pi}{12}$ multiples memorized, there are 4 of them:
$$\cos(\frac{2\pi}{3}) = -\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\cos(\frac{3\pi}{4}) = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$
$$\cos(\frac{5\pi}{6}) = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$\cos(\frac{11\pi}{12}) = -\frac{\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{6}}{4}$$
(If you don't recognize that last one, note that $\frac{11}{12} = \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{4}$, and use the sum-of-angles identity.)
You can then calculate:
$$f(\frac{2\pi}{3}) = \frac{8\pi - 33}{6} < 0$$
$$f(\frac{3\pi}{4}) = \frac{3\pi - \sqrt{2} - 10}{2} < 0$$
$$f(\frac{5\pi}{6}) = \frac{10\pi - 3\sqrt{3} - 30}{6} < 0$$
$$f(\frac{11\pi}{12}) = \frac{22\pi - 3\sqrt{2} - 3\sqrt{6} - 60}{12} < 0$$
$$f(\pi) = 2\pi - 6 > 0$$
By the IVT, $x \in (\frac{11\pi}{12}, \pi)$.  Intersecting that interval with the previously-known $x \in (2, 3)$, we get:
$$\boxed{x \in (\frac{11\pi}{12}, 3)}$$
So, somewhere between 2.879793 and 3.
If you want an exact solution, and computers and numerical root-finding algorithms are off-limits, I don't think you'll be able to do much better.  Unless you have access to trig tables.
